# ROC curve using random forest data doesn't look right

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am trying to plot an ROC curve using random forest data with:

```
mdl <- randomForest(QdataTrainX, QdataTrainY)
m<-predict(mdl,QdataTestX)
OOB.x <- predict (mdl,QdataTrainX,type="prob");
OOB.pred <- OOB.x[,2];
pred.obj <- prediction (OOB.pred,QdataTrainY);
RP.perf <- performance(pred.obj, "rec","prec");
plot  (RP.perf@alpha.values[[1]],RP.perf@x.values[[1]],type="l",ylim=c(0,1));
```

here is my ROC curve:

[image: ROC Curve 1]

I am using data that has been published

test data - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iDswLYaZ0zVENwUUhENnhZeTg/edit?usp=sharing
training data - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iDswLYaZ0zdXN6UzU3Y3pPUEU/edit?usp=sharing

, where the ROC curve they demonstrate goes through the origin:

[image: ROC Curve 2]

which leads me to think I am misusing a parameter somewhere. Can anyone see anything wrong with my code?

Comment: It would really help if you pointed us to an easily accessible version of the data, or gave a small sample of it. The ROC curve that you generated is not impossible, so it is hard to tell if something went wrong.

Comment: @will update with data.

Comment: There's no Y in either of those datasets. And there are only 6 observations in the 'test.csv' set, so it's not surprising that the ROC curve looks strange.

Comment: which makes no more sense to me as to how they produced their ROC curve